# Service's onCreate() called every time StartService is run

Tags: android, android-service

I have a class that receives screen activity and will run the below line whenever the screen is unlocked.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context, myService.class);
context.startService(intent);
```

My issue is that this will run my service's onCreate() every time the screen is unlocked. This leads to multiple copies of myService running when I only need one. I've tried a variety of solutions, but to no avail.  My understanding is that if the service is running, then onCreate() gets passed over and it goes straight to onStartCommand().

I've pulled up a list of running services right before this code is executed and myService is never listed.

Not sure what I'm doing wrong here...

Comment: Does `myService` extend `Service` or `IntentService`?

Comment: My bad, meant to say that earlier.  myService extends Service

Answer (score 0):

I've been facing the same problem once.
Finally, I found it's because I used  stopSelf(msg.arg1) everytime I call the onStartCommand(). I fixed the problem by simply deleting the stopSelf(). Hope it help.

Answer (score -1):

To prevent calls to oncreate every time you start your service return `START_STICKY` from `onStartCommand`.  This will keep the service around till you kill it.

```
@Override
    public void onCreate() {
        // get the notification manager
        mNM = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
            // other stuff etc.
        context = this.getApplicationContext();
    }


    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        // the service is started so after all clients are unbound it stays
        // running
        return Service.START_STICKY;
    }
```

Good Luck

Comment: "This will keep the service around till you kill it" -- no, it does not. It tells Android to automatically recreate the service if Android terminates the process to free up system RAM, once the RAM situation improves. This will, in turn, cause a call to `onCreate()`.

Comment: @CommonsWare what I've found is if the process is busy doing something like storing gps coods every five seconds it won't be killed.

Comment: Also @CommonsWare if the user reboots the device the service will be killed but that's another question on intents.